# Convert MAC address to byte array in C#

Tags: c#, type-conversion, arrays

I have a simple MAC address as a string, `"b8:27:eb:97:b6:39"`, and I would like to get it into a byte array, `[184, 39, 235, 151, 182, 57]` in C# code.

So I split it up with the following:

```
var split = str.Split(':');
byte[] arr = new byte[6];
```

And then I need some sort of `for`-loop to take each substring turn them into a 16-bit int.
I tried `Convert.ToInt8(split[i])`, `split[i].ToChar(0,2)`, `(char)split[i]`, but I can't figure out how to take to string-characters and let them be a single 8-bit number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

here you go

```
string mac = "b8:27:eb:97:b6:39";
byte[] arr = mac.Split(':').Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x, 16)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Answer of the day! Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest using PhysicalAddress class instead of doing it yourself.

It has a Parse method:

```
PhysicalAddress.Parse("b8:27:eb:97:b6:39").GetAdressBytes();
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.networkinformation.physicaladdress.parse(v=vs.110).aspx

But it will fail as the method only accepts `-` as byte separator. A simple extension method can help:

```
    public static byte[] ToMACBytes(this string mac) {
        if (mac.IndexOf(':') > 0)
            mac = mac.Replace(':', '-');
        return PhysicalAddress.Parse(mac).GetAddressBytes();
    }
```

Then use:

```
byte[] macBytes = "b8:27:eb:97:b6:39".ToMACBytes();
```

Edit: Included suggestions.

Comment: Sorry about that. Better?

Comment: much :) though I'm not sure that is what the OP wants?

Comment: @Toxantron, would be better if you suggest OP to use `PhysicalAddress.Parse(str).GetAddressBytes()` and then provide the references you have provided.

Comment: I see, It display English on my machine. :(

Comment: This will throw an exception as `PhysicalAddress.Parse` accepts only `-` as a separator. I've edited the answer with a solution.

Comment: The part about using the `PhysicalAddress` class should be the accpeted answer. I'm not a big fan of adding an exstension method to `String` to get a MAC address, that seems like improper use of extension methods to me.

Comment: After .NET 5, colon character is also a valid separator

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Byte.Parse method of the .Net framework.

```
byte value = Byte.Parse(split[1], NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
```